# SUMIF calculation with little complication on my side

Tags: vlookup, sumifs

Please see the file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzuFuPfITC9IeVNydUtJWEVHSFE/view?usp=sharing

I would like to have the current formula (without change) working but only with selection of the country name. so for example, when B1 is UK, it will do the rest of the formula for rows with UK in Column "E" on Qty tab.

Please write the formula on the file.

I hope I've explained my question well enough.

Appreciate your help in advance.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, there are no UK data in the data sheet, so I guess you should first make up your mind on whether you go for UK or GB. Also, how can we make your formula working for a particular country *without change*? It will have to change for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP...))`! What you really want is `SUMIFS()`. This is the formula for B2:

```
=SUMIFS(Data!F:F, Data!C:C, A2, Data!E:E, $B$1)
```

And if you want it to be draggable onto column C right away, just modify some `$`'s, like this:

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$F:$F, Data!$C:$C, $A2, Data!$E:$E, B$1)
```

As @trincot says, you need to change `UK` to `GB` first to see it work ;-)

EDIT after your comment:
Sure, just wrap another `IF` around it:

```
=IF(B1="GB";IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A:A, Data!C:F, 4, 0)), "0",SUMIF(Data!C:C, Master!A2, Data!F:F));"Whatever")
```

Comment: Above is the link with UK changed to GB. thanks for that.

Comment: Now, as I mentioned earlier, I do not want to change the rest of the formula as it has more complications which I've just deleted to protect the privacy of the data info.

Comment: I just want the formula to work for the specific country codes such as GB, DE etc. can we add another IF string at the beginning? can you please give me exact formula?

Comment: It did not work for me for some reason. Could you please use the excel file and fill in the exact formula?

Comment: Anyone up for help please?

Comment: In my formular, you probably need to replace the semicolons (`;`) with commas (`,`). Try that and tell me if it worked.

Comment: Well at least the error is gone. but the formula need to ignore the values when the first "IF(B1=GB, does not justify. and so forth.

Comment: Anyone up to help on this?